# Server-side debugging not working [Meteor 1.2]

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, meteor, webstorm

Before I get into the details, please note:

1. I'm using Meteor 1.2 and the latest version of WebStorm 11.
2. Client-side debugging works fine, at least using the Chrome Web Inspector, client-side logging is shown in the console.

My issue is I can’t get server-side debugging to work. I’ve now tried all of the following to no avail:

1. Running `meteor debug` and launching Node Inspector (it hooks into my Meteor instance but doesn’t log anything server side or hit any breakpoints I've set using `debugging;` statements in the code, code execution was not suspended)
2. Launching Meteor from WebStorm, `putting console.log()` statements all over the place. Nothing would get printed, breakpoints wouldn’t be hit
3. Running `meteor shell` and trying to see logging there
4. Using Atom IDE instead, however this is not suitable for me because of a company proxy which the Atom plugin manager isn't able to circumvent (doesn't route proxy info).

Comment: `meteor shell` doesn't print any logging output. All of that goes to the console where meteor was started. Where did you start it? Did webstorm start meteor?

Comment: In #2, I start Meteor using WebStorm. In #3, I start Meteor using the command line.

Comment: console.log in server-side code works fine for me when running from WebStorm; breakpoints are hit, but not for the very first time - I need to re-run Meteor run configuration in debugger to get them work (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19334)

Comment: Looks like WS 11.0.2 broke this (https://forums.meteor.com/t/debugging-not-working-for-meteor-1-2-apps-in-webstorm/10407/30). How do I download 11.0.1, your website's previous versions page only shows versions 10 and older and no place to download minor versions...

Comment: Fortunately, typing this in by hand worked: http://download.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-11.0.1.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WS 11.0.2 definitely broke this. Although not listed on JetBrains' website, typing in the download executable URL for WS 11.0.1 by hand (http://download.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-11.0.1.exe) allowed me to get back to the previous minor version. After installing 11.0.1, I am able to debug my code in the WebStorm IDE, set and hit breakpoints and see server-side logging.